# youtube-dl: how to skip already downloaded files in python script?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Via Python script I want to configure youtube-dl to not download already downloaded files.

I understand rejecttitle option is available to achieve this goal.

I need an example on how to pass an array or dictionary of files already downloaded to youtubedl via rejecttitle.

Comment: Have you read the api https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since version 2015.03.28, youtube-dl does this automatically (when resuming is possible). Therefore, simply updating your installation of youtube-dl should suffice.

With a prior version, you can set the [`continuedl` option](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/4747e2183acbddea61a3f10fb4ba1ed5b70c8bd1/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py#L34) in your invocation.

You may also be interested in the [`download_archive`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/4747e2183acbddea61a3f10fb4ba1ed5b70c8bd1/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L180) option, which allows you to keep a list of all downloads you've ever run and check this list instead looking whether the file exists.

Comment: Doesn't work with the -x flag